# Send link on Telegram channel from Python without preview

Tags: python, telegram

I send a message on telegram channel using this method:

```
telegramResult = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramApiKey + '/sendMessage', params={
    'chat_id': '@XXXXXX',
    'text': 'hello world' + getShortLink
})
```

The problem is that telegram view a preview of this short link. I don't see this preview.

Please, can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. Now I use method sendPhoto (teleport library) and when I add shortlink I don't see more the preview image.

Answer (score -1):

```
telegramResult = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramApiKey + '/sendMessage', params={
    'chat_id': '@XXXXXX',
    'text': 'hello world' + getShortLink
})
```